# Oracle utl_nla_array_dbl does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, permissions, package

Trying to get ordinary least squares regression going using the `UTL_NLA` package in Oracle.

The `UTL_NLA` package is installed by default and appears to be working. Next up, I tried to run some of the regression sample code (OLS_Regression) that ships with Oracle (`olsexmpl.sql` and `olstype.sql`). I am able to create the model just fine, but when I try to use it, i get the error

```
<schema_name>.UTL_NLA_ARRAY_DBL does not exist.
```

I am pretty sure that it does exist. What permissioning am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTL_NLA_ARRAY_DBL is an Oracle type, and seems to have both a PUBLIC grant and synonym in a standard installation, so you shouldn't be seeing this error.  You should see from a query of the dictionary views:

```
select owner, grantee, privilege 
from dba_tab_privs 
where table_name = 'UTL_NLA_ARRAY_DBL'
    OWNER      GRANTEE    PRIVILEGE
    ---------- ---------- ----------
    SYS    PUBLIC     EXECUTE

and 

select owner, synonym_name, table_name 
from dba_synonyms 
where table_name = 'UTL_NLA_ARRAY_DBL';

    OWNER      SYNONYM_NAME           TABLE_NAME
    ---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
    PUBLIC     UTL_NLA_ARRAY_DBL          UTL_NLA_ARRAY_DBL
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I experimented with the sample code some more and got it to work.

Comment: My problem was caused by an empty result set.